# Git duplicated all the commits

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

[image: diverged]
Hi! I came to an issue where somehow all the commits are duplicated, and the main branch diverged from origin/main.

I'm new to git, and I tried `git reset HEAD~1 --soft`, but it did nothing.

I searched for an hour but couldn't fix it. I don't have local changes but I have lfs files and .gitignored files that I don't want to lose. Any way I can fix this without recloning the entire repo? Thank you!

Comment: Did you run a `rebase` recently iinvolving local or remote `main`?

Comment: I don't think so...I tried to solve some other issue and ran lots of commands. I think probably git lfs migrate messed this up... idk. Now I only want to discard the local 128 commits and not affect the origin or lfs/ignored files basically

Comment: `git lfs migrate` would do it: it *copies* the original repository (all 128 commits) to a new, different repository (a new set of 128 commits) in which the large files do not exist any more. Instead, in the *new* repository, the large files have been replaced with "placeholders" ("LFS pointer files"). The LFS wrappers, which wrap Git, know how to replace the placeholders with the *real* files, which have been set aside and are no longer in the Git repository at all: they're now to be stored on a separate, non-Git server.

Comment: If you wish to use Git-LFS, throw away the *original* repository (or keep it but archive it and stop using it) and save the *new replacement repository* as a new, different repository, in which there are no large files. The large files will be stored elsewhere, on a separate large-file-server, and you *must* use the LFS wrappers from now on.

Comment: If you wish *not* to use Git-LFS after all, throw away the new repository, clone the original again, and don't run `git lfs migrate`.

Comment: just to mention : rather than a screen capture of a terminal, copy/paste the text in your question. You can insert an "unformatted" block of text by enclosing it between two `\`\`\`` lines (three backticks), or by prefixing each line with 4 spaces (just like the `{} code` button of the editor does).

Comment: Thanks! Since I have lots of ignored files that are essential despite not in the repo and the repo is not owned by me, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to throw away the original repo. However, the repo is a scratch space basically, will it break anything if I just pull and push the duplicated commits? It's definitely not the best practice, but I'm wondering what is the safest option? Thank you!

Comment: Ahh ok I did `git reset --hard origin/main` to just discard all the local commits and now it's all up to date.